# Porting a C# lambda expression to PHP

Tags: c#, php, lambda, porting, strategy-pattern

I was going through this [blog post](http://dotnetcodr.com/?s=open%20closed%20principle) about the OCP and I was trying to port the code from C# to PHP.
I'm having difficulty porting this function:

```
public class PricePerUnitStrategy
{
    public bool IsMatch(OrderItem item)
    {
        return item.Identifier.StartsWith("Each");
    }

    public decimal CalculatePrice(OrderItem item)
    {
        return item.Quantity * 4m;
    }
}
public class DefaultPriceCalculator
{
    private readonly List<IPriceStrategy> _pricingRules;

    public DefaultPriceCalculator()
        {
            _pricingRules = new List<IPriceStrategy>();
            _pricingRules.Add(new PricePerKilogramStrategy());
            _pricingRules.Add(new PricePerUnitStrategy());
            _pricingRules.Add(new SpecialPriceStrategy());
        }

    public decimal CalculatePrice(OrderItem item)
    {
        return _pricingRules.First(r => r.IsMatch(item)).CalculatePrice(item);
    }
}
```

How do you covert the `CalculatePrice` function to PHP preferably using PHP's lambda expressions?

Here is what I was able to do so far:

```
class OrderItem{
    public $Identifier;
    public $Quantity;
}

class PricePerUnitStrategy{
    public function IsMatch(OrderItem $item){
        return $item->Identifier=="Each";
    } 
    public function CalculatePrice(OrderItem $item){
        return $item->Quantity * 4;
    }
}

class DefaultPriceCalculator{
    private   $pricingRules;
    public function __construct(){
            $pricingRules = array();
            $pricingRules[]=new PricePerUnitStrategy();
        }
    public function CalculatePrice(OrderItem $item){
        return $pricingRules->First(r => r.IsMatch($item))->CalculatePrice($item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show what the `IsMatch` method is, is it an extension method?

Comment: @DavidG I added the `PricePerUnitStrategy` class to show what the `IsMatch` looks like. I'm not familiar with C# or PHP lambda expressions, so I'm not sure how it is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after a little bit of reading on closure I was able to port it to PHP as follows:

```
public function CalculatePrice(OrderItem $item) {      
    return array_filter($this->pricingRules, 
        function ($r) use ($item) {
            return $r->IsMatch($item);
        })[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would do something like this

```
public function CalculatePrice(OrderItem $item){
    foreach ($pricingRules as $rule) {
       if ($rule->IsMatch($item)){
          return $rule->CalculatePrice($item);
       }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Because, I think, but I am not sure, that the `.First` exist in php, so you have to write yourself the same logic. Also, about the final `return null` you might want to raise an exception, as you didn't used `.FirstOrDefault`